# Remove border in PreferenceFragment when inflate custom layout

Tags: android, layout, border, inflate

How remove border when i créate `PreferenceFragment` with custom layout.
This is my code:

```
public static class CommsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_comms);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View aux = inflater.inflate(R.layout.config_custom, null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

My `custom_layout.xml` contains `ConstraintLayout` with `button` and `listview`.

Custom layout has a background color. When load `PreferenceFragment` an border white background is automatically added.

Here screenshot with API >21 and API < 21
[image]

What I can do to eliminate it?

Thanks

Here's another screenshot:

[image]

Can be seen as a padding of 32 left and right are automatically added . How I can force the parent layout , ie FragmentPreferenceLayout have padding to 0?

Comment: If i debug, i see ViewGroup container have mBorderLeft and mBorderRight = 48..... ¿Why? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Although if someone has a better one, I would like to know.
In addition, continued without knowing why.

Here my solution, add code in PrefenceFragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.config_custom, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        View container_parent = (View)view.getParent();
        container_parent.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    }
```